# Azure Windows AppService hosting .NET Core 5 app can't use Invoke-Command ("Service WinRM was not found on computer")

Tags: azure, powershell, .net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have .NET Core 5 application deployed to native Windows AppSerice in Azure.
Inside application I run Powershell command:

`Invoke-Command -Computer '{endpoint}' -Scriptblock {{{scriptBody}}} -Credential $credential`

where `endpoint` is private IP address of Azure VM running Windows I want to run a script on.

AppService has been added to the same Vnet as Azure VM using VNet integration feautre so both "machines" are reachable for each other.

While executing `Invoke-Command` I get:

`An error has occurred which PowerShell cannot handle. A remote session might have ended.`

Then I tried `Enable-PSRemoting` but I get:

`Access is denied. To run this cmdlet, start PowerShell with the "Run as administrator" option` - which is understanble. I didn't exepct AppSerice would allow to run admin cmdlets.

I also tried `Set-Item WSMan:\\localhost\\Client\\TrustedHosts -Value 'endpoint'"` and I get:

`Service WinRM was not found on computer '.'`

WinRm service is not available for Native Windows AppService? It means I cannot use remote Powershell features from AppService at all? Or I need to install or enable it somehow in Azure Portal?

PS. I tried to run exactly the same `Invoke-Command` from "VM to VM" (not AppService to VM) then it works perfectly well so that script is executed (I needed to add the IP to TrustedHosts though).

Comment: You need to run `Enable-PSRemoting` _on the remote VM_, not in the AppService instance

Comment: `Enable-PSRemoting` is enabled on remote VM (I could run VM to VM Invoke-Command as I wrote)